# Expose Django from a C++ service

Tags: python, c++, django, wsgi

I'm writing a service (daemon) which provides web-unrelated features to my users.

I'd like to implement a minimal web server in that service such that a user can connect on say `http://localhost:5000` and get an overview of the service current status. I've read a lot on embedding/extending Python and on how the latter seems to be recommended. However I can't decide how to design this: my service entry point has to be on the C++ side (it's a system daemon and one might not want to compile it with the web-server feature).

I'd like to use something like Django to be able to handle the requests (routing, security, whatever) on the Python side where many, many things already exist. I already have a minimal HTTP server in C++ (mongoose) that can process simple requests but I'd really like to delegate the actual processing to Python, pretty much the way WSGI does.

What is a good approach here ?

Comment: Keep in mind that there are a few web frameworks in C++ as well. If you want to stick with Python, I would consider making this management side a second process/service and doing some IPC between the two.

Comment: If you insist on embedding Python, go all the way and let it be the web server as well. Both CherryPy and Tornado can serve as WSGI containers for Django, but they might provide enough by themselves not to bother with a relatively huge framework like Django. You may then use Boost.Python for example to embed Python in C++.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien It's not so much that I insist, but I do have these requirements and I just don't see what other solution there might be. Good idea, letting the web server by Python as well: I didn't really thought of that.